# Getting results of pattern-matching: more faster as ArrayList or as Object?

Tags: java, regex, match

I am writing an app that has one thing as main focus: speed. It has to be as fast as possible.
I want to get all the matches for a specific regex.

```
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
```

What I used to do is:

```
ArrayList<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
        while (matcher.find())
        {
            String match = matcher.group();
            matches.add(match);
        }
```

Now I am wondering if it would be faster to return a String in case the match is only 1 and of course an ArrayList if matches are more than 1.
So, if I do this I would need to change the return type from ArrayList to Object.

Is it faster this way?

Comment: ... but then you will need to get this object's type (class) and cast it back.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Java is statically typed and strong typed. When we return two completely different types by the means of returning an `Object`, we sacrifice type safety. --- Do you have an actual performance bottleneck? Because ["*premature optimization is the root of all evil*" -- Donald Ervin Knuth: *Computer Programming as an Art* (1974), p. 671](https://dl.acm.org/ft_gateway.cfm?id=361612&ftid=289767)

Comment: logic: so it will need to keep track of first found element until the end or until the second element is found, in which case a list is created, both found elements added and further elements added to the list... That is, for each iteration check if there is already a list created, or the first element found. I have a feeling that wouldn't be much faster... (or faster at all)

Comment: What you’re proposing will have little to no effect on execution speed.  If you really want to improve the speed, avoid using a regular expression and do the work yourself, assuming the pattern isn’t complicated.  For example, if you’re just looking for a substring, you don’t need a regular expression at all.  If you’re just looking for a word, it’s not hard to iterate through the characters yourself to find word boundaries.

Comment: Create a timestamp of now, write a Loop which does the operation 5000 times, create another timestamp of now, subtract the First imestamp and get the needed time. Do this for both methods.